# iOS: send touch events to view behind if touch is within specific area

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, touch-event

I've got a view A which contains some custom UI controls. View A is bigger than it's UI controls appear on screen. View A is in `ViewController` A which sits on top of `ViewController` B (VC B is a property of VC A).
I want to tell my gesture recognizer, that when the user taps within a specific area in view A, view A should not respond to touch events at all, but should be consumed and processed by views inside VC B.

I tried setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false once the user touches within a specific area in view A, so that touch events would automatically be process by views behind view A (or VC A).
The problem is, that one `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to false, I am no longer able to respond to touch events in the correct area of view A.

Is there a better way to send touch events to a view behind view A only if it is in a specific area of view A?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `pointInside` method to make View A in controller A to avoid handling events, the effect is like what `isUserInteractionEnabled` does. And you will also have a way to calculate the specific area.

Example:

```
class ViewA: UIView{
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        //assume this area has no response
        let areaNoResponses = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100) 

        if (areaNoResponses.contains(point)) {
            return false;  //no response, like ViewA.isUserInteractionEnabled = NO
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when will this method be called? Furthermore, at runtime, I would like to make view A cover the fullscreen with more UIControls visible. That would require me to change `areaNoResponses`. And because viewA has animations, I need a way to trigger the call to `point()`at the beginning of my animation.

Comment: `pointInside` method will be called automatically when the user is touching the screen. When touching event happens, the system will pass the event in this order: `UIApplication->UIViewController->UIView`, so most of the UIView has an opportunity to tell the system if it will handle the event or not, that is what `pointInside` or `hitTest`'s job.  For animation and other cases, you could provide a property for `areaNoResponses`, and change it when the area is changed.

Answer (score 0):

> VC B is a property of VC A

I am assuming that VC B is a child view controller to VC A.
Now, if View A is covering up the views of VC B, then you have no other choice but make view A respond to touches. Likewise if These are detached view controllers and detached views, tapping on view A will always make it respond to touches.

The thing you can do is detect exactly when you want views of VC B respond to touches on view A and pass the required information to VC B. And a function in VC B will execute required task as you intend.

Example:

```
VC A:
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:action:)
viewA.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Assuming VC B has been initialized beforehand
    vcB.handleGestureFromVCA()
}

VC B:

@objc func handleGestureFromVCA() {
    // Code for VC B's views go here
}
```

Hope this helps. If not, then please share what you have tried with us.

Comment: this approach could work, however, it would require a lot of work. ViewController A has a MiniPlayer (like Apple Music app) and sits on top of a `tapviewcontroller`. So passing touch events to every tab on the tap controller and manually respond to those touch events would result in a lot of work.

Comment: You can do one thing to reduce the amount of work. **You can make a master view controller with some common methods and UI elements inside it (remember to code for that. Outlets will lead to crashes).** And then in the sub class of master view controller such as `VC A` and `VC B` `override` the *common functions to respond to touches*. You can rather implement a listener through `notification center` and post to it upon touch.